# How to implement Controlled Components (in ReactJS) using Vanilla JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

How can I implement Controlled Input concept in ReactJS using Vanilla JS or JQuery ?

Tried with `oninput` but it will be triggered only after the value has changed in the text box.

Here is my code example which should prevent user from entering a value greater than 999. If user enters 1000 it changes to 999 but should stay at 100.

```
<input name="count" id="groupcount" oninput="changeQuantityInGrid(this.value)">
....
function changeQuantityInGrid(quantity) {
        var maximun_connection_count = 999;
        if (quantity > maximun_connection_count){
            $('#groupcount').val(maximun_connection_count);
        }
}
```

Comment: plz share your code

Comment: Your

 code is correct, what's the problem?

Comment: yes its working fine.. just tried...whats the problem bro

Comment: if user enters 1000 it changes to 999 but should stay at 100.

Comment: got it, look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

Just use `$("#groupcount").maxValue(999);` to apply this on any input

```js
$.fn.maxValue = function(maximun_connection_count) {

  this.each(function() {
    var value;
    $(this).on('input', function(e) {
      var quantity = e.target.value;
      if (quantity > maximun_connection_count) {
        $(this).val(value);
      } else {
        value = e.target.value;
      }
    })
  })

}

$("#groupcount").maxValue(999);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="count" id="groupcount">
```

Comment: what if I want to implement this for multiple inputs. ? declaring `value` as a global wont be a sensible solution.

Comment: Now try it, I've created a jQuery function for that

Comment: Worked like a charm (with some minor modificaion to accept only digits).

Answer (score 0):

Here hows you do it in React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    quantity: 0
  }
  changeQuantityInGrid = (e) => {
    const val = +(e.target.value) > 999 ? this.state.quantity : e.target.value
    this.setState({
      quantity: val
    })
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input name="count" value={this.state.quantity} id="groupcount" onChange={this.changeQuantityInGrid} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Click on the link to run the demo
https://repl.it/repls/HardtofindTechnologicalCurrencies

thanks :)

Comment: I need to do it without react